# How to run quakusIntTest against a running application using gradle?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

The [testing guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#executing-against-a-running-application) states that you can run integration tests using against a running app using:

`./mvnw verify -Dquarkus.http.test-host=1.2.3.4 -Dquarkus.http.test-port=4321`

I am trying to the the same thing, but using gradle:

`./gradlew quarkusIntTest -Dquarkus.http.test-host=1.2.3.4 -Dquarkus.http.test-port=4321`

However it did not worked.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: @geoand it tries to run the app again from the test-runner instead of testing the already running app

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you open an issue on GitHub please?